# Combine two plots from two different chunks in R studio (markdown)

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, r-markdown, chunks

I'm currently working in Rstudio with Markdown and Knittr, but when you try to combine two plots from two different chunks (with par('data')) it creates a seperate plot. I guess for some reason when using a new chunk it doesn't remember the old plot in the other chunk.

I hope someone has a solution for this :)

Code example:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
mu=180
m=n=30
sd=100
nu=seq(175,185,by=0.1)
B = length(nu)
p = numeric(B)
for (b in 1:B) {x=rnorm(m,mu,sd)
  y=rnorm(n,nu,sd)
  p[b]=t.test(x,y,var.equal=TRUE)[[3]]}
power = (1-p)
plot(nu,power,type="l", col='blue')
```
````

**** Some text with first plot ****

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
mu=180
m=n=100
sd=5
nu=seq(175,185,by=0.1)
B = length(nu)
p = numeric(B)
for (b in 1:B) {x=rnorm(m,mu,sd)
  y=rnorm(n,nu,sd)
  p[b]=t.test(x,y,var.equal=TRUE)[[3]]}
power = (1-p)
plot(nu,power,type="l",col="red")
```
````

**** Some text and then both the plots should be combined/end up in 1 figure ****

Comment: If you want them to appear in the same (first) plot why not add the second chunk to the first and use points to add the second plot to the first?

Comment: Because I have to put a description between the first and second chunk, if you create one chunk i won't be able to add anything in between. And the data is the same (except for 1 value) so hard to combine in 1 chunk.

And using points(...) in the second chunk gives this error:
"Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet"

Comment: ah you need 2 plots, then marcos answer should work

Comment: Yep: https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/